# Mensaje de confirmación - Reset/Limpiar formulario - Javascript

Tags: javascript

En un `formulario` suele haber botones y uno de éstos es el de "**Limpiar/Resetear**", cual en muchos códigos `HTML` viene definido de la siguiente manera:

```
<input type="reset" value="Limpiar" id="limpiar" name="btnLimpiar"/>
```

al ser de tipo "`reset`" si aceptamos la pregunta de **confirm()**, limpiará automáticamente todos los campos que hayamos rellenado.

Mi pregunta es:

**1)** ¿Se debe realizar algo en el código al comprobar que la respuesta es true? Por ejemplo: `document.getElementById("miformulario").reset();` //donde "`miformulario`" es el nombre del `id` del `<form>`

Si realizo este código me retorna el siguiente error:

```
funciones.js:360 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of null
    at confirmLimpiar (funciones.js:360)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (funciones.js:154)
```

**2)**¿Qué código debo asignar al "else" si no quiero que realice nada (es decir, que hemos pulsado el botón "Cancelar", ¿return false, null?

Código asociado al evento del botón "onclick":

```
    miformulario.btnLimpiar.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
        return confirmLimpiar();
    }, false);
```

Comment: el null es por algun error de id

Comment: verifica si el formulario tiene id <form id="miformulario">

Comment: Cierto tenía otro nombre en el form id, arreglado. Ahora el problema viene en el apartado 2) ¿Cómo hago para que al pulsar en Cancelar no borre ningun campo? Es decir, que no haga nada....

Comment: debes llamar a `e.preventDefault();` siendo `e` el evento del callback.

Comment: te he dejado un ejemplo de como hacerlo, Saludos!! ;))...

Comment: @omaza1990 Creo que este artículo te puede ser útil: [¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debo usarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 1):

Debes utilizar el metodo preventDefault().

Ejemplo:

```js
miformulario.btnLimpiar.addEventListener("click", function () { 
 if (!confirm("Desea Limpiar el Formulario?"))
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form id="miformulario">
codigo<br><input><br>
nombre<br><input><br>
<input type="reset" value="Limpiar" id="limpiar" name="btnLimpiar"/>
</form>
```